# Determining which diode I need

Tags: diodes, integrated-circuit, repair

I have the following board with the below diode:

[image]

One diode fails circuit testing and needs replacing, but how do I find out the specification of the diode I should buy to replace it?

(it is for a synthesiser)

Thank you!

Comment: It's a diode. Not a resistor.

Comment: Desolder that diode and read out the numbers. It might be a fast diode like 1n4148 or a zener diode. However I feel chances of it being a fast diode is far greater than a zener.

Comment: Ah OK, sorry, I'll update the question with diode!

Comment: How did you determine failed circuit test?

Comment: If you can google search the service manual for that synth, it'll confirm the part number once and for all.

Comment: @jippie I used a circuit tester a bit like this: http://img.directindustry.com/images_di/photo-g/63984-4111425.jpg

Comment: Did you check the diode both directions? Compare it with the other ones? Best is to desolder at least one side as @Whiskeyjack mentioned, then do the check.

Comment: @jippie yep I did both sides, all the other diodes passed the test, but only this one failed, which seems to align with the keys that are broken. Read out the numbers from the circuit tester, do you mean?

Comment: My bet would be that a simple 1N4148 will suffice, but that's just gut feeling. US $6,54 for 500pcs including shipping, first hit on eBay. What I mean by that is, be careful not to overpay for generic diodes. The other ones are correct, you really want to try find service manuals to verify my hunch.

Comment: As I inspected it ahead of desoldering, I noticed it was broken in half which explains the fact it's not working. If I can't find the service manual, is there anything I can do to be sure I buy the right diode?

Comment: You could desolder (carefully) a working one, check it thoroughly for markings, and confirm its voltage drop with a DMM.

Answer (score 3):

Likely any diode will work -- the diode is used to read the keyboard from an MCU.

Most common diodes like that are 1N914, or 1N4148. A 1N4001 (or 4002, 4003.. 4007) would probably also work.

How did it fail ? How do you know it is failed ? Did you unsolder one end and check it is bad ?

Answer (score 2):

It's more modern that my ancient Roland JX-3P (circa mid 80s from memory) but I had a similar problem and I just replaced the diode - it was a 1N4148 or 1N914 (both a pretty much identical) and it fixed the keys that didn't work. I had a similar problem on an old Casio too where i damaged one of the diodes by being too heavy handed. Out came the trusty 1N4148 to save the day. I don't think you'll cause any problem by fitting the worng diode just don't use a zener diode.